# boto s3 - write a csv file using array

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I want to upload a file to s3 without writing the file on my local system, so I am using set_contents_from_string of boto library. I am able to upload this file back to s3.

But how to write an array to a csv file using boto library.

```
arrlist = [[2, 'jack'], [3, 'john'], [4, 'robert']]
file_name = "test.csv" 
k = Key(bucket, file_name)
k.set_contents_from_string(arrlist)
```

Its not accepting array, any help how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

First, turn the array into multi-lines string.

```
arrlist = [[2, 'jack'], [3, 'john'], [4, 'robert']]

i = 0
multiLine = ""

for item in arrlist:
    newLine = ','.join(map(str, item))

    if (i > 0) {
        multiLine = multiLine + '\n'
    }
    multiLine = multiLine + newLine
    i++

file_name = "test.csv" 
k = Key(bucket, file_name)
k.set_contents_from_string(multiLine)
```

The output `multiLine`, which is written to file will be like:

```
2,jack
3,john
4,robert
```

Hope this help!